# SBT cannot find snapshots in an Artifactory maven repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm just starting out trying to set up a workflow with scala and sbt, and I'm having trouble with my repository.  I am trying to publish a simple test library, which is composed of two projects, and use it from another program.

My source library's build contains the following:

```
val sharedSettings = Seq(
  name := "test-lib",
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.0",
  publishTo := Some("Artifactory Realm" at "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local"),
  publishMavenStyle := true,
  credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / ".credentials")
)

lazy val root = project.in(file(".")).settings(sharedSettings: _*).aggregate(child1, child2)

lazy val sharedCode = project.settings(sharedSettings: _*)

val child1Settings = sharedSettings ++ Seq(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <++= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in sharedCode) in Compile)

val child2Settings = sharedSettings ++ Seq(unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <++= (unmanagedSourceDirectories in sharedCode) in Compile)

lazy val child1 = project.settings(child1Settings: _*)

lazy val child2 = project.settings(child2Settings: _*)
```

I can run sbt publish okay, and it creates the directory `com/example/test-lib/XXX` in the repo.

In my test program, I have the following:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.0",

resolvers += "Artifactory Realm" at "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local",

libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "test-lib" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

When the test program attempts to compile, it cannot resolve `com.example`, because of the following:

```
[warn] ==== Artifactory Realm: tried
[warn]   http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/example/test-lib_2.11/0.1-SNAPSHOT/test-lib_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Looking at the repository directory itself, I am getting an additional timestamp on my pom files:

```
test-lib_2.11-0.1-20140510.183027-1.pom               10-May-2014 19:30  793 bytes
test-lib_2.11-0.1-20140510.183027-2.pom               10-May-2014 19:30  793 bytes
...
test-lib_2.11-0.1-20140510.183121-9.pom               10-May-2014 19:31  793 bytes
```

maven-metadata.xml in the directory is referencing these okay, sbt is looking directly for a pom file without a timestamp and cannot find it.  The pom files contain the correct information.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's looking to `my-repo` as an ivy style repo, but you've defined it correctly in your sample as a maven style repo. However, your output says `my-repo` and your sample says `Artifactory Realm` so you've modified something when you posted this up. Can we see the original so we know where its called `my-repo` from.

Comment: Good catch! I was messing around with ivy vs maven repos earlier and must have copied it from the wrong console window...  Actually I understand the problem more and will adjust my question to reflect this, one moment.

Comment: Try adding publishMavenStyle := true to your build.sbt which might remove the timestamps when you pubish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue was not with my sbt configuration after all, but with my repository server.

I'm using Artifactory, and the snapshots repository was configured to use "unique snapshots" by default.  The filenames of these snapshots are modified as they are published to include a timestamp, which sbt 13.x doesn't seem to understand.

After changing the repository's "Maven Snapshot Version Behaviour" from "Unique" to "Nonunique", everything started to work.

Comment: Has a bug been filed with Jfrog for this? Because Maven3 in Jfrog only supports unique. I am having this same frustrating issue.

Answer (score 1):

actually, the inconsistency of timestamp & build number suffix in maven-metadata.xml and jar/pom files genereated by `sbt publish` lead to such error.

[image]

with the following plugin [sbt-maven-resolver](https://github.com/ericxsun/sbt-maven-resolver) during deployment procedure, the suffix will be kept same, looks like:

[image]

currently, adding this plugin on the deployment side (once the timestamp & build suffix are same, both sbt/maven can find the snapshots):

in `plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt" % "sbt-maven-resolver" % "0.1.0")
```

hope to solve your case.