# sbt not able to resolve snapshot dependency

Tags: maven, sbt, snapshot

I am sure that this has already been asked before, but I do not seem to be able to find answer. So, please excuse me if this is duplicate.

I need to link to the dependency `"org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native-platform" % "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT"` which is available at http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots To do that I have added following to the build.sbt file

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)
libraryDependencies += "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native-platform" % "0.8.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

However when building my code I get error

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.nd4j#nd4j-native-platform;0.8.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

and the sbt output is

```
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from /home/p/projects/genia/sim/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/p/projects/genia/sim/project/}sim-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to sim (in build file:/home/p/projects/genia/sim/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/p/projects/genia/sim/}sim...
[info] Resolving org.nd4j#nd4j-native-platform;0.8.1-SNAPSHOT ...
[warn]  module not found: org.nd4j#nd4j-native-platform;0.8.1-SNAPSHOT
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/p/.ivy2/local/org.nd4j/nd4j-native-platform/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-native-platform/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/nd4j-native-platform-0.8.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /home/p/.sbt/preloaded/org.nd4j/nd4j-native-platform/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////home/p/.sbt/preloaded/org/nd4j/nd4j-native-platform/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/nd4j-native-platform-0.8.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[warn] ==== Sonatype Snapshots: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/nd4j/nd4j-native-platform/0.8.1-SNAPSHOT/nd4j-native-platform-0.8.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.nd4j#nd4j-native-platform;0.8.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.nd4j:nd4j-native-platform:0.8.1-SNAPSHOT (/home/p/projects/genia/sim/build.sbt#L13-14)
[warn]        +- default:sim_2.11:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.nd4j#nd4j-native-platform;0.8.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
```

If I add this dependency to build.xml and use maven than it works just fine, but not in sbt. Is there something I am doing wrong?
Is there something I am doing

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585401/651140

Comment: I think it is issue on sbt - ivy.